# understanding caching in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

On view page I have loaded content inside tabs. On user click inside tab I'm sending ajax request to the controller which sends back partial view. Everything works and now I want to implement caching on this tab content.  So, I want to on first tab call content to be loaded and then cached for 60 sec. and the same for every other tab content.

I tried something like this

```
[DonutOutputCache(Duration = 60, VaryByParam = "activeTab")]
public ActionResult GetTabData(string activeTab)
{....}
```

but this display cached content of the first tab in every other tab.

Comment: @User....you'll probably need to use Session and store each individual tab upon its first request: Session.Add("tab1",data), etc

Comment: Where is `DonutOutputCache` defined?

Comment: @jrummell inside reference dll (DonutCacheAttribut)

Answer (score 0):

Where is DonutOutputCache attribute defined? Maybe it isn't properly using VaryByParam?

[In MVC 3 you no longer need to specify the VaryByParam option on the built-in OutputCache attribute.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/10/announcing-asp-net-mvc-3-release-candidate-2.aspx)

```
[OutputCache(Duration=60)]
public ActionResult GetTabData(string activeTab)
{....}
```

Should be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had success using caching Attributes on Actions in my ASP MVC projects.  One of my co-workers says that he uses them and it works, but I've always had to either tell a page not to cache using this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
```

Or including cache: true / false in my $.ajax

```
$.ajax({ .... cache: false, ... });
```

Comment: hm, I was thinkig that this might work but nothing changed with cache: false.

Answer (score 0):

**Please refer below links.it's give proper details in output catching**

[OUTPUT CACHING IN ASP.NET MVC](http://juristr.com/blog/2012/10/output-caching-in-aspnet-mvc/)

**Improving Performance with Output Caching:**

[Improving Performance with Output Caching](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs)